# Cannot Access Firebase Snap Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a firebase structure set up as follows:

[image]

Each key contains data that I want to use to populate a UICollectionView. However, I am having difficulty accessing the Firebase data. In Android, I used a method similar to

```
dataSnapshot.child("xxx").getValue()
```

However, that type of accessibility does not appear to be available in iOS. Below is the method I am trying:

```
     self.dataSource = self.collectionView?.bind(to: self.ref.child("Polls")) { collectionView, indexPath, snap in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PollCell
        /* populate cell */
        cell.pollQuestion.text = snap.child("question").getvalue
          print(indexPath)

        return cell
    }
```

I am receiving an error that states Value of type "FIRDataSnapshot" has no member child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this line on Android:

```
dataSnapshot.child("xxx").getValue()
```

On iOS it would be:

```
snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "xxx").value
```

I highly recommend using the Firebase reference documentation for this type of problem: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#-childsnapshotforpath. The number of methods in a `FIRDataSnapshot` is not all that big and it will allow you to make progress a lot faster.

Comment: Much appreciated Frank